# equation with double fractions

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ \frac{\pi + \frac65\pi}{2}=\frac{11}{10}\pi $$

I've found this equation in some of the examples, we've got this equation, so as I think:

$$ \frac{\frac{5}{5}\pi + \frac{6}{5}\pi}{2}=\frac{11}{10}\pi $$

then:

$$ \frac{\frac{11}{10}\pi}{2}=\frac{11}{10}\pi $$

how could the result be: $$ \frac{11}{10}\pi $$ ??

if there is still the division by 2?, or I'am missing something, please any help, how to solve this double fraction equation?

Comment: $\frac{5}{5} + \frac{6}{5} = \frac{11}{5} \neq \frac{11}{10}$

Comment: @DanielFischer oh my god, thats what I've missed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator of your third step should read$$\dfrac55 \pi + \dfrac65 \pi = \color{red}{\dfrac{11}5\pi}$$